# How to change a numpy array in to a specific matrix with 0 and 1

Tags: python, arrays

Suppose we have an numpy array like;

```
a=[1,1,2,3]
```

how we can change 'a' into a 4*4 matrix like:

```
[0 1 o o
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1]
```

I mean, by calling each element, it give us a vector with the value of 1 in the corresponding index.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if numpy has any predefined functions to do this, but a simple way to do this via `for` loop would be -

```
In [61]: a
Out[61]: array([1, 1, 2, 3])

In [83]: i = np.zeros((a.shape[0],a.max()+1))

In [84]: for x,y in enumerate(a):
   ....:     i[x,y] = 1
   ....:

In [85]: i
Out[85]:
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```